# Redirect emails based on the extention with postfix

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

I have email alias called `reports` which I like to redirect to a default subset of emails. But I'm looking to implement something like sending emails to `reports+reportName` and have a different subset of emails which I redirect to, And in case there is no rule for `reports+reportName` it will default to `reports`.

reports: user1, user2
reports+xxx: user3, user4

- Sending a mail to `reports+xxx@` will go to user3 & user4
- Sending a mail to `reports+yyy@` (which is not exists) will go to user1 & user2

I found a way using a local account with `.forward+EXT` files, but I don't like it much, I much prefer to have a single place where I can manage the redirect/overwrites and not a separate file for each.

Comment: Sounds like you already have a solution? If you need to go more dynamic, postfix maps and sieve offer great options (and: a shared IMAP folder may be better than forwarding to multiple individuals anyway)

Comment: The above example is a bit simplified, in reality i have many more groups, so a shared inbox is not a an option.